# react router with spring boot rest api

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, react-router

I've created react app with routing as client, and java spring boot responsible for server.
The server has the adnotation:
`@RequestMapping("/elements")`

And the client router should catch everything (maybe except "elements").
I have created route like:

`` <Route path=`/${myVariable}` component={<App />} /> ``
where `myVariable` represents some unique id. Lets say it is "asdf".

But now i write URL like "/asdf" i get the white page and error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

I expected react router to catch it, but it didn't. It looks like spring tried to catch it because error comes from java, not js.

Can you tell me what should i add (maybe some configuration) so it will work?

Comment: React Router is for single page applications (SPA). If you are routing to your Spring Application, it is no longer a SPA.

Comment: I have routes to the server to fetch data after big calculations...

Comment: Routes are used to change the page, i.e. update the dom. It's not for fetching new data.

Comment: @emsiiggy This is not what a Router is for. It is solely used to decided which components to render depending on the current location